# What is the trick to creating a responsive WPF UI when populating multiple ListBoxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, dispatcher

I am working on a support tool that displays multiple `TabItem`s in a `TabControl`.  Each `TabItem` represents an employee, and within each of these employee `Tab`s there is another `TabControl` which contains additional `TabItem`s.  These `TabItem`s represent Outlook folders for that employee (like "Working", "Completed", etc).  Each of these folder `TabItem`s contains a `ListBox` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `MailItem`s that pertain to that Outlook folder.  These aren't huge collections - only a dozen or so items per `ListBox`.  Although, in total, across all `TabItem`s there could conceivably be 100 items or so.

The way I have currently built the application is that the app fires up and populates the screen with the appropriate employee tabs and sub-tabs. This process is fairly quick and I'm happy.  I have created a Static `Global.System.Timer` that all folder `TabItem`'s code-behind is synchronized with.  So every 5 minutes the application will clear all `ObserverableCollection`s and re-scan the Outlook folders.

The problem is that the scan process brings the application to a halt.  I have tried using a `BackgroundWorker` to gather mail from Outlook as a background process, then pass a `List<MailItem>` object to a `RunWorkerCompleted` method that then runs a `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` process that clears the respective `ObservableCollection` then adds the items from the `List<MailItem>` back to the `ObservableCollection`.  I've even set this `Dispatcher` to the lower priority.

Despite this, the application is very clunky feeling during the scan/populate `ListBox` process. I am unclear on how to better design this and I admit I am somewhat new to this.  I realize that clearing out each of the `ObservableCollection`s is inefficient, but Outlook folder change events aren't particularly reliable, so I need to do a brute force re-scan every once in a while to insure all `MailItem`s are represented.

Below is my code for the WPF control that contains the `ListBox`.  Keep in mind that there are about 10 of these `ListBox` controls active at once.

```
// This entire UserControl is essentially a ListBox control
public partial class TicketListView : UserControl
    {
        private TicketList _ticketList; //this is the ObservableCollection object
        private Folder _folder;         // Outlook Folder

        public TicketListView(Folder folder)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _ticketList = this.FindResource("TicketList") as TicketList; 
            _folder = folder; 

            GlobalStatics.Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        private void Refresh()
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<MailItem> tickets = new List<MailItem>();
            string filter = TicketMonitorStatics.TicketFilter(14);
            Items items = _folder.Items.Restrict(filter);

            try
            {
                foreach (MailItem mi in items.OfType<MailItem>())
                {
                    tickets.Add(mi);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception) { }

            e.Result = tickets;
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<MailItem> tickets = e.Result as List<MailItem>;

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(delegate
                {
                    _ticketList.Clear();
                    PopulateList(tickets);
                }));

            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            worker.Dispose();
        }

        private void PopulateList(List<MailItem> ticketList)
        {
            foreach (MailItem mi in ticketList)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(delegate
                    {
                        _ticketList.Add(mi);
                    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems a bit odd you are having such big performance issues with such little data, I have a similar app, Tabbed outlook mailreader that includes folders with upto 5000+ items and this does not hang the UI, What kind of `Timer` is `GlobalStatics.Timer`, I use a `Threading.Timer` which eliminates the need of a `BackgroundWorker`, Is there also Images associated with these mail Items?

Comment: Doesn't the RunWorkerCompleted handler run on the thread where the BackgroundWorker was created? If that is the case you shouldn't need to use a Dispatcher to run code on the UI thread since you're already on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your requirement, specially in WPF, you shouldn't be using timer or background worker to keep the view responsive. Instead you  should be designing your app with MVVM pattern. MVVM is Model, View and View Model, where if there is a change in the model, the model updates the View Model, and the view model updates the view. This is done by just inheriting a "INotifyPropertyChanged" Interface.

Here is a simple example

Xaml part:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="259" Width="445">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-3">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="32" Padding="0"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And The .cs Part

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace SimpleMVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private AnimalViewModel _animal= new AnimalViewModel ();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = _animal;
            button.Click += (sender, e) => _animal.Name = "Taylor" ;
        }
    }

    public class AnimalViewModel : AnimalModel 
    {
        public AnimalViewModel ()
        {
        }        
    }

    public class AnimalModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                PropertyChanged(this, args);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

No imagine that the button click is the update triggered by scheduler, you model get updated first that trigger a property changed event to update the view.

Using this pattern your code will be much reliable.

I hope this helps.

Regards
Jegan

Comment: Ehh. Where is your viewmodel? I only see view and model.

Comment: Your code is alright, but i'm not sure if you can call it MVMC. I've never seen VM inherit from M

Comment: As this is a simple example, I chose the VM to inherit the M, however if the design gets more complicated, it would rather VM instantiate the M.